# ng2-admin aot build unable to fetch images, fonts from assets

Tags: angular2-template, angular2-aot, ng-admin

I am using ng2-admin template following their installation guide https://akveo.github.io/ng2-admin/articles/002-installation-guidelines/ it is running perfectly in local but when I am creating production build using "npm run build:prod:aot" and running it on server the project is able to fetch js files but all assets getting 404. I have tested by defining base href in index.html but uanble to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just updated two files below:
1. src/app/theme/sass/conf/_variables.scss

```
$assets-root: '{replace to your path}/assets';
```

2.src/app/theme/sass/_icons.scss

```
@include svg-icon('{replace to your path}/assets/img/' + $iconName + '.svg', $width, $height);
```

Enjoy it

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if the assets actually exist on the server? Are the assets getting copied to the build directory and deployed?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, so I changed the file "_ng2.scss" to the following:

```
line 68:  $mainBgUrl: "../../" + $assets-root + $images-root + 'sky-bg.jpg';
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution at last.

Please edit "package.json" to the following image.

I added line 29:
[image]

Here I deployed to http://localhost/ng2admin/dist on my local machine.

And then:

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\ng2admin> npm run build:demo
```

This was my final solution.

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing. Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.